# Reveal a field based on multiple radio selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been asked to reveal an further radio input only **when a certain combination** of radios are selected! Is this possible? (Borrowing script from here: http://jsfiddle.net/wdckktz7/ )

Html

```
<div><input type="radio" id="option 1" name="group1" value="A" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" id="option 2" name="group2" value="B" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" id="option 3" name="group3" value="C" /></div>
<div id="combined"><input type="radio" id="option 4" name="group4" value="D" /></div>
<!--When option 2 and option 3 are checked then option 4 is revealed-->
```

Script

```
$("input[name=group]").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 'A' & 'B' && $(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#combined").show();
} else {
    $("#combined").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: What do you intend for this to mean? - `if ($(this).val() == 'A' & 'B' && $(this).is(":checked"))` ... the single `&` in `'A' & 'B'` is a _bit-wise and_ operator, not a logical operator.

Comment: Hi Stephen - I'm very fresh on coding! Was trying to show that both A and B need to be selected before D will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for changes to the relevant radio inputs and evaluate whether the additional radio should be shown or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/rat15ba5/2/

```
$('[name=group1],[name=group2]').change(function() {
   var op = (
       $('[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'A' &&
       $('[name=group2]:checked').val() == '2'
   ) ? 'show' : 'hide';
   $('#a2')[op]();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou arcyqwerty - this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the fiddle too - really helpful for me to see it all in action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes every time a new radio button is selected, you will need to store which one was selected, and you will need to check if the desired combination of selections matches your selection history.

You could list the past selections by pushing the id of each button into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to give the determining radio buttons a common name & class, say `name="group1"` and `.radio` respectively, so you can select them easily and set an event listener on them like so:

```
$('.radio').on('change', function() {
    var r = $('.radio');
    $('#combined')[(r[1].checked && r[2].checked ? 'show' : 'hide')]();
})
.change();
```

```js
$('.radio').on('change', function() {
    var r = $('.radio');
    $('#combined')[(r[1].checked && r[2].checked ? 'show' : 'hide')]();
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="radio" id="option 1" class="radio" name="group1" value="A" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" id="option 2" class="radio" name="group2" value="B" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" id="option 3" class="radio" name="group3" value="C" /></div>
<div id="combined"><input type="radio" id="option 4" name="group4" value="D" /></div>
<!--When option 2 and option 3 are checked then option 4 is revealed-->
```

Comment: Hi PeterKA
Thank you for your answer - I was wanting option 4 to reveal when both 2 and 3 are selected together. I appreciate your help on this though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's a lot easier to achieve; my answer is updated.